# beginner jQuery tabs - add easing effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jQuery ui tabs with the following code but am having trouble adding easing or changing the speed of the effect:

```
$('#tabs-mcr > ul').tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
```

standard opacity toggle but I'd like to either speed up the fade effect or add custom easing to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#tabs-mcr > ul').tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: "fast" } });
```

or if you want a certain amount of milliseconds:

```
// half a second
$('#tabs-mcr > ul').tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 500 } });
```

Comment: that's done the trick, thanks. If anyone has a solution for adding easing with the jQuery easing plugin that would be cool.

Comment: nevermind this seems to work:

$('#tabs-mcr > ul').tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 'fast', easing: 'easeInOutCubic' } });

Comment: If the solution works, can you mark it as accepted? That helps the system, other users, and me.

Comment: Sorry. There is indeed a 15 minute restriction. I didn't want to be obtrusive, I was just wondering if the solution was OK enough. Thanks!